# Heroku CSS and Image files Not Updating?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, assets

I have read other questions with similar issues and tried their fixes to no avail :(

I have a rails app, where when I make changes in the CSS files or add images to the assets/images directory, followed by pushing the code to heroku, the site does not update. Heroku is continuing to work off old versions of my css files.  It updates changes made to the HTML files, but not to the CSS or images. My GitHub repo for the site updates correctly, and is tied to the app. I am fully up to date commit wise.

I have tried `heroku run rake assets:precompile` followed by `heroku restart` and still nothing.  I have cleared my cache and all browsing history before testing and again nothing.

Some background: It is currently a free app; will this affect my issue? Also, the app can be found at [here](http://arcane-badlands-8218.herokuapp.com).  For me, I can only see an image for the top project, and all my projects have 0 margin between them, though my local CSS file (and GitHub version) dictate a margin.

The code itself can also be found [here](http://github.com/mful/MySite).

Thanks for reading! I would be really grateful for some insight on this issue!

Comment: is it an option for you to precompile your assets before you deploy?  I think I had this issue before and committin the compiled assets to the repo fixed it.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions here? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3x-asset-pipeline-cedar
Also, are you sure you are pushing to Heroku and not just GitHub? That will probably require two separate `git push` commands.

Comment: @jvnill That did it!  Post it as a response rather than a comment so I can mark it as answered for others who have this problem in the future.

Comment: there you go. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the comments: Precompiling assets and committing them to the repo is another option so you don't let heroku handle asset compiling.